# NavigationBar not positioned correctly. How to solve this problem?

Tags: iphone

I have a Navigation Controller in my main view and also subview. And I use the following code to add the navigation view when needed.

In appdelegate.h page

```
    @interface AapkeappsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
AapkeappsViewController *viewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController; 
}
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AapkeappsViewController *viewController;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
 @end
```

In appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    UINavigationController *nvcontrol =[[UINavigationController alloc]   
               initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window addSubview:nvcontrol.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
return YES;
}
```

This code work when press the button

```
Homepage * rootViewController = [[Homepage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Homepage"   bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  
initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

However, the navigation bar is not positioned correctly. I have posted a pic below. Anyone knows what is the potential problem? And how to solve this gap of navigationbar? Help me anyone. Thanks in advance. Here i can post the image. So i have posted a pic in the link [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZ7J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

you first load your View controller than after load your navigationController instead this only navigationController.VIew you have to add on window..

hope it`s solve your problem.

Comment: but next page contain two navigation bar same hav the gap between the navigation bar. How to solve this.

Comment: for next page you can add navigation bar manually... on that view.

Comment: The next page code is                                               Homepage * rootViewController = [[Homepage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Homepage" bundle:nil];
 navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
 [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view]; How to solve this